# OpenGL shaders not working?

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I've made a class in Java using LWJGL which imports shaders and enables them and disables them so when they are enabled I get some cool effects. The problem is that every time I initialize my class it crashes and it's apperenly due to a "glCreateProgram" function.

```
public class Shader {
private int Shader;
private int VShader;
private int FShader;

public void InitShader() throws IOException, Exception
{
    Shader = glCreateProgram(); //This is where the exception is thrown.
    VShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    FShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    StringBuilder VSHADER_SOURCE = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder FSHADER_SOURCE = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("shader.vert"));
        String text1;
        while ((text1 = reader1.readLine()) != null)
        {
            VSHADER_SOURCE.append(text1).append("\n");
        }
        reader1.close();
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("shader.frag"));
        String text2;
        while ((text2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)
        {
            FSHADER_SOURCE.append(text2).append("\n");
        }
        reader2.close();
    glShaderSource(VShader, VSHADER_SOURCE);
    glCompileShader(VShader);
    if (glGetShader(VShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE)
        throw new Exception();
    glShaderSource(FShader, FSHADER_SOURCE);
    glCompileShader(FShader);
    if (glGetShader(FShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE)
        throw new Exception();
    glLinkProgram(Shader);
    glValidateProgram(Shader);

}

public void EnableShader()
{
    glUseProgram(Shader);
}

public void DisableShader()
{
    glUseProgram(0);
}
}
```

It worked, and them randomly stopped on me. Can you figure out what's happening?

Comment: Could we see the exact exception getting thrown?  Thanks!

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Hmm... Could we see the code where you're calling this function?  Also, it would be nice to see the whole exception text.

Comment: Is OpenGL context already created before you create the shader program?

Comment: Can you clean up the code please? Why is the class called Shader? Why do all variables and method names have capital letters. I don't like been one of those guys that comments on practice but I think that's half the problem here.

Comment: @MichaelIV has a legitimate question. user1939871, you may be surprised to find out that if there is no OpenGL context current on the current thread, most implementations just silently return with absolutely no indication of a problem, besides nothing happening. Depending upon which function it is, it may link enough opengl to seem to have a valid entry point, or may require you to use some platform specific variant of `getProcAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

Create class containing this method anywhere:

```
public static final void check(String errorMessage) {
int errorValue = GL11.glGetError();

if (errorValue != GL11.GL_NO_ERROR) {
String errorString = GLU.gluErrorString(errorValue);
System.err.println("ERROR - " + errorMessage + ": " + errorString);

if (Display.isCreated()) Display.destroy();
System.exit(-1);
}
}
```

And put `YourClassName.check("things that just happened few lines above - just to know where you should seek for errors")` at the end of every setup method or even more often.

The error you get means that you broke something in your shader programs and they cannot be compiled properly, so your java code should be fine. Maybe I can help more if you post your shaders code.